# Does there exist an optimal solution $(x^*,y^*)$ to $\max x^TAy$ such that $x^*=y^*$?

Tags: inequality, optimization

Given two positive integers $n \le m$ and non-negative real constants $a_{ijkl} \ (1\le i,k\le n,1\le j,l\le m)$.

Let $M$ be the set of $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ satisfying:

- $X\ge 0$,
- The sum of each row of $X$ is $1$,
- The sum of each column of $X$ is less than or equal to $1$.

Define 
$$F(X,Y) = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^m a_{ijkl}x_{ij}y_{kl}$$

Question: does the following hold?
$$\max_{X,Y\in M} F(X,Y) = \max_{Z\in M} F(Z,Z)\quad (*)$$
In other words, does there exist an optimal solution $(X^*,Y^*)$ to $\max_{X,Y\in M} F(X,Y)$ such that $X^*=Y^*$?

Note that $F(X,Y)$ can be written as $x^TAy$ where $A=(a_{ijkl})_{1\le i,k\le n,1\le j,l\le m}$ and $x,y$ are respectively the column-wise vectorized replica of $X,Y$.

My goal is to find conditions on $A$ such that $(*)$ holds.

Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: Obviously, $\max_{X,Y\in M} F(X,Y) \ge \max_{Z\in M} F(Z,Z)$, thus it suffices to check $\max_{X,Y\in M} F(X,Y) \le \max_{Z\in M} F(Z,Z)$.